# I want to change part of a filename to relfect the folder name using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to change multiple file names to reflect the folder name it's in

Files are called all similar to this `Bf110G2_Orange 603 v1`, I would like to swap the `BF110G2` bit to the name of the folder it's in. So one folder is say `ju88a4` so I would like file name change to `ju88_Orange 603 v1`

I have 6 files to do and about 50 folders to do it in so I would like do it with a batch file can anyone help?

Can anyone help

Thanks

I tried this but I'm not a programmer and I don't know the syntax for changing it to work

```
Echo OFF

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("Bf110G2_*") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `for /?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. Then run `dir /?` and read the output help. Last run `ren /?` and read again the output help. The task can be done with a batch file containing just the following single command line: `@for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "Bf110G2_*" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @for %%H in ("%%~dpG.") do @for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%I in ("%%~nxG") do @ren "%%G" "%%~nxH_%%J"`

Comment: That is awsome worked perfectly thank you very much